# Issue in collection view flow layout

Tags: ios, ios8, uicollectionview, autolayout, flowlayout

I am using collection view in ipad, it had 3 columns

Everything looks good if items count is in multiple of 3.

If whenever , I show items and itemscount%3=2 spacing are changed in last row.

I use below methods:

```
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40.0;
}
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40.0;
}
-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
    insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(40.0,40.0,40.0,40.0);
}
```

[image]

Please look at spacing at last row..

Answer (score 0):

You are defining **minimum** item spacing, so I suggest you actually measure the distance of items on previous rows vs. last row.

My guess is that distance on your last row might actually be the defined 40 and that it's more on earlier rows (where available row width has been evenly divided between items).